# Solarium - Need to update read-only resultset

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I'm building an interactive search service for a client, and part of what we need is the ability to add "tags" to documents.  These tags will be both pre-existing and custom-defined.  The schema has been setup to support this, but I'm having issues with Solarium PHP on updating a resultset.

For example, if the user searches for "Overflow" in our database, and that returns 1-1000+ results, they need to ability to tag this entire resultset with any number of tags.

So I'm taking the resultset from execute() and am currently unable to alter the documents returned -- the exception being "A readonly document cannot be altered".

Any one have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

For an updateable document you should use this class: **Solarium\QueryType\Update\Query\Document**

> Solarium uses this document type as default for select queries for two
>   reasons:
>
> in most cases no update functionality is needed, so it will only be
>   overhead to discourage the use of Solr as a DB, as in reading -
>   altering - saving. Almost all schemas have index-only fields. There is
>   no way to read the value of there fields, so this data will be lost
>   when re-saving the document! Updates should normally be done based on
>   your origin data (i.e. the database). If you are really sure you want
>   to update Solr data, you can set a read-write document class as the
>   document type for your select query, alter the documents and use them
>   in an update query.

http://solarium.readthedocs.org/en/stable/documents/